# Whats the best way to do a loop for listview selections

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a listview that is populated by list of checkboxes..I want to add a button that when I press it it do sth for each item which user is selected in listview..Whats the best way to find what check box is checked?I know I can use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` but how I call if for each checkbox in my list?and If I create an array string and each time my checkbox checked it addes its text to array list can I then do loop for each selected item?
here is my code to pupulate list view

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_database_list);
    File path=new File(ClubCP.SDcardPath);
    List<String> file_lists =   main.directoryPath(path);
    ListView Database_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.database_list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.database_list_item,R.id.chk_database_list_item,file_lists);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this,file_lists);
    Database_list.setAdapter(adapter1);

}
```

I searched and I think I must use a ArrayAdapter ..I am writing its class..this is my class
package co.tosca.persianpoem;

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

      private final List<String> list;
      private final Activity context;

      public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<String> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.database_list_item, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
      }

      static class ViewHolder {
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
          view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.database_list_item, null);
          final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
          viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_database_list_item);
          viewHolder.checkbox
              .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                  ///do sth

                }
              });
          view.setTag(viewHolder);
          viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
          view = convertView;
          ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }


        return view;
      }
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: what do you mean by `do sth`?

Comment: check this: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/multi-selection-listview-android-with.html

Comment: Thanks for your help,@user603125 I mean here I want to add selected items to an arrey list or sth like that..I am working on it..@Dhaval Sodha Parmar I already found this example.Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass ArrayAdapter and override the `getView` method so you can call `setOnClickListener` on a per-view basis. See ArrayAdapter docs: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View itemView = convertView;
    if (itemView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        itemView = li.inflate(R.layout.database_list_item);
    }

    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox); // whatever the id of checkbox is in layout
    cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox myCb = (CheckBox)v;
            if (myCb.isChecked()) {
                // add position to array representing selected items
            } else {
                // remove position from array
            }
        }
    });

    return itemView;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot,I used your code but now I get error in `  View itemView = convertView ? getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.database_list_item);` and cant compile It says `Syntax error, insert ": Expression" to complete Expression`

Comment: Sorry, that's an operator from c# (null coalescing operator to be exact). I'll update the code snippet to fix it.